# Passing an address or a pointer to C function

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, pass-by-reference

In the following two pieces of code, I don't get why the latter one gives a segmentation fault. I apparently wrongly assume that I'm passing an address in both cases... A pointer is an address right?

So this one works:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int test(char *a) {
        *a = *a + 15;
        return 0;
}
int main() {
        char b;
        b = 'c';
        cout << b;
        test(&b);
        cout << b;
}
```

It outputs:

```
r
```

But this one gives segmentation fault, why?:

```
...

int test(char *a) {
        *a = *a + 15;
        return 0;
}

int main() {
        char *b;
        *b = 'c';
        cout << b;
        test(b);
        cout << *b;
}
```

Comment: In the second example the variable `b` is a pointer. But when you dereference it, *where does it point?* Remember that uninitialized local variables really are uninitialized.

Comment: So how would I initialize it and then point it to one character? I mean without a second variable. I understand I can do char b = 'c' and then char *d = &b, but that would give me the same as in the upper example...

Comment: It will work if you write: `char a= 'c'; char *b; b = &a;`

Comment: What else would you do? If you have a pointer it *must* point somewhere valid for you to be able to dereference it.

Comment: Your code is C++ not C.

Answer (score 2):

Because memory for `b` isnt allocate here:

```
char *b;
```

Examples works:

```
char *b = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
*b = 'a';
```

```
char a = 'a';
char *b = &a;
```

```
//C++ only
char *b = new char[1];
*b = 'a';
```

Comment: Why the [1].. does not seem to make a difference (char[1] instead of char)

Answer (score 0):

> But this one gives segmentation fault, why?

**b** - it is a pointer to address in memory.
In line `*b = 'c';` you are assigning to not initialized area some value.
To avoid it you should understand that before to assign any value **in** pointer you should initialize refer for b.

```
    char *b;
    /*-------*/
    char bb;
    b = &bb;
    /*-------*/
    *b = 'c';
    cout << b;
    test(b);
    cout << *b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because defining a pointer does not mean that the memory is allocated for your program.

```
 char *b;
 *b = 'c';
```

This is undefined behavior since the pointer can point to anything.

There are two ways to fix this.

```
char *b;
char ch = 'c';
*b = &ch; // taking the address of ch
```

Now `b` is pointing to the statically allocated `ch`.

There is a way with dynamic allocation.

```
char *b = malloc(sizeof(char));
*b = 'c';
free(b);
```

Comment: You can also sometimes benefit from using your own memory allocation using a large array, search for `obstack`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as @Some programmer dude already mentioned: In the second example the variable b is a pointer and it points to an undefined address. However the best way to declare and initialize a pointer is like this:

```
char *b = NULL;
```

In the first example the variable b is saved/lies on the stack. You can use it.
On the second example, like mentioned, you have only a pointer. If you want to use a pointer in this context you have two options:

1. Use a local (stack variable) and assign the address to the pointer like this:

   ```
   char a = 'c';
   char *b = &a;
   ```
2. Use the heap. So get memory from the heap to use your char-pointer. This means the char-pointer points to an address on the heap:

   ```
   char *b = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1); // allocate space on the heap
   b[0] = 'c' // or *b = 'c'
   ... // do some stuff and then
   free(b); // don't forget to free your allocated space
   ```

Comment: Your point 1 is not limited to stack variables. It works for any type of variable.

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, declaring a pointer does not mean that the variable points to a valid memory address. Think a pointer as an address card, the sole purpose of it is telling you the address of a memory block (in heap).

It is your responsibility to make sure that address pointed by your pointer variable is a valid memory block. How do you make a memory block a valid allocated space? Well, you use one of the `malloc` family functions or the `new` keyword (C++ only).

```
char *c; // Just an address somewhere
c = malloc(10); // Now, the address pointed by c is a 10 byte long memory block
.....
.....

free(c); // return the allocated memory to OS when you are done
```

In your code, you do not allocate memory for your pointer. Where does it point to? Is the address pointed by your uninitialised pointer variable a valid memory block? No.